# Авторизация в админке роутера

Tags: c#, роутер

Пытаюсь авторизоваться в админке роутера. Прогнал авторизацию через снифер. Отловил 2 GET запроса на адрес 192.168.1.1. Ответ на первый запрос  - код 401(запрос на авторизацию), а на второй - 200(успешно). Но Нигде не увидел ни логина, ни пароля. Как они передаются при такой авторизации?

P.S. по идее они должны передаваться в заголовках в поле Authorization, такое поле есть во 2-м запросе и оно содержит значение

```
Basic YWRtaW46WGloMDUwZXRyYXRhdGE=
```

Я не понимаю как оно формируется.
Помогите разобраться и написать авторизацию. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это строка username:password в base64. Можно сформировать кодом вида:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
```

В вашем случае - это результат вызова `Convert.ToBase64String("admin:Xih050etratata")`

Как ее передать вместе с запросом - зависит от метода, которым вы делаете запрос:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
// тут сам запрос
```

или

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

и WebClient, и HttpWebRequest отправят эти Credential в ответ на 401 код.